# Position FIXED Is Making My Images Overflow, Even With > overflow: hidden;

Tags: html, css

This is the header, so it's all that I've written so far, but for some reason, my pictures are longer than my header.

The pic is from the lower part of the header where they overflow.
[image of the overflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7DkT.png)

```html
    <header>
        <img id="bg-img" src="images/head-img.jpg" alt="bg">
        <img id="logo" src="images/logo-black-bg.png" alt="logo">
    </header>
```

```css
header {
    margin: 0;
    height: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #000;
    position: relative;
}

#logo {
    width: 18%;
    max-height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 5%;
}

#bg-img {
        width: 60%;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
```

Comment: Why did you fix the images instead of the header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing how `position` works, as your header is not actually useful for anything, as all elements contained within are positioned `fixed`, which means they take their width, height and position reference frame from the *viewport* and *not* your header element. I also do not understand why you would place a background image there if CSS provides a perfectly fine `background` property that can be controlled with much more ease.

For your purpose I would suggest something like the example below, but I would even go further and tell you that positioning your logo absolute is going to be a pain at some point - you add menus, text, etc... to your header and all of a sudden objects are behind your logo. In that case, a better solution might be a flexbox:

```
header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: right;
    align-items: stretch;
}
```

If you now add padding to your header, your logo will get it for free as well.

```css
body {
  height: 200vh;
}
header {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 25vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #000;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: url('http://via.placeholder.com/300x200/444444');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}
#logo {
    width: 18%;
    max-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 5%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img id="logo" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="logo">
</header>
```

I also adjusted your headers height, but only to ensure that it shows up correctly and you can visualise some scrolling and a fixed header.

Comment: Thank you so much. Even after 3 months of constantly working on CSS, I still have some sort-of holes in my knowledge that are just absolutely ridiculous. I honestly appreciate your help! Thanks!